# Remote RESTORE of database through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, restore, connectivity, tcpip

How can I `RESTORE` a database through SQL Server Management Studio by connecting "remotely" to it?

If I know the "IP address" of the target machine what else do I need to know?

If the port number is a requirement, how can I find it?

I only know the IP address of the target machine. I want to know on which port the SQL Server runs. I am given the task to connect to the SQL Server instance and take a backup.

Comment: Follow the steps described in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4317/2374) to get your remote connection working. Read the documentation on [Backing Up and Restoring Databases in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx) for the basics.

Answer (score 2):

[What TCP Port is SQL Server running under?](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/02/02/what-tcp-port-is-sql-server-running-under/) by Colin Stasiuk details several ways to determine the port number SQL is running on

- go right to the registry and look at the TCP settings

  **SQL 2005**

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\
    MSSQL.<InstanceNumber>\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\
  ```

  **SQL 2008**

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\
    MSSQL10.<InstanceName>\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\
  ```
- `xp_readerrorlog`.  This will show the current SQL Server log and you
  can find the row "Server is listening on".
- use the SQL Server Configuration Manager
- if you are on the machine, look at Task Manager

Then you should be able to use 'IPAddress, Port' to connect.  Or you can create a client side Alias using `CliConfg` on the client that allows you to connect to an alias.